# Jekyll default yaml front-matter not accessible via liquid

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid, templating

On my personal site, I style the post list on my home page based on the post's category. So if I have the front matter:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "My Post"
date:   2016-01-26
category: code
---
```

Because the category is `code`, the div below will render to have a css class `card-code` and style the post excerpt accordingly.

```
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <div class="col-1-2">

      <!-- This Line! -->
      <div class="paper-card card-{{ post.category }}">

         <!-- other code -->
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

To try to make my life simpler, I set the default category for posts to be `general` in my `_config.yml` file:

```
default:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      category: "general"
```

However, `{{ post.category }}` comes up with nothing for these posts (i.e., `card-`). Any ideas why this ain't working?

Comment: Jekyll version please. A repository url can be even better.

Comment: You may need to use the pre-build version of the posts folder for the type: field in your default conf. e.g. type: "_posts"

Comment: or possibly, the singular "post"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation at [Front Matter Defaults](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) the section should be called `defaults` not `default`.

Try this in your `_config.yaml`

```
defaults:
  -
scope:
  path: ""
  type: "posts"
values:
  category: "general"
```

Comment: My gosh, I've poured over this and yet I still didn't see that. Thanks Robert, I'll give this a shot tonight.